# putting @Html.DisplayFor in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.actionlink

in asp.net mvc, I have a view with name index that show one html table as a grid.
suppose this is this my html table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Caption
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Caption)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CityId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CityId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CityId }) |
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

now I want put `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Caption)` in the text of `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CityId })`

but i give an error from mvc.

Comment: Seeing what doesn't work will be more helpful than seeing what does work.  Show us the code that you tried that's broken.  It's likely just the inclusion of the `@` symbol from your description, but hard to say.

Comment: i want to use this  @Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Caption), "Edit", new { id=item.CityId }). error say cannot resolve method actionlink .........

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the correct method overload, like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Caption, "Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CityId }, null)
```

Comment: It's a pleasure to help! :)